# About "discussion to chat"

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

I asked some question and someone answered And then I comment on the answer.
And he also comments on my comment. And I comment on his comment, and so on.

Then the following sentence appeared

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

If I click the button then we may be in a chat room.

Here my question is: Who makes the sentence? Does he, who answer to my question, invite me? Or this site, i.e., [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com), reply to them, who give comments, for prohibiting comments?

Comment: It is automatically generated by the StackExchange software when it detects that a few users are repeatedly commenting on each others comments. Comments were never designed for extensive conversations and the software tries to redirect you to a more appropriate corner of the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is automatically generated by SE.

Generally, extended comments are discouraged, and it is recommended to take it to a chat room so that comments can critique questions and answers. Moderators automatically get a flag when there is 20 comments on a post, so it's encouraged that you move it to chat yourself. It automatically creates a link to a brand new room as well.

If someone else invites you t chat, you may see a comment by another user like this:

> Let us continue this discussion in chat.

With a link to the chat room.